# Scroll navigation drawer to bottom at item click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hello i am new to android. I want the navigation drawer scroll to bottom on an item click. Is it possible?

```
 if (id == R.id.setting){
     --CODE--
}
```

Here if setting is selected i want the navigation drawer to scroll down to bottom. How can it do it? please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, id.settings is a button, to add the functionality when a user clicks a button you should use this code:

```
Button settingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
            settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    --CODE--
                }
            });
```

Comment: its not button. Its an item on navigation drawer. When that item is clicked i want the navigation drawer to be scrolled at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`onNavigationItemSelected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html#onNavigationItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) to handle `NavigationDrawer` items.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

       case R.id.setting: {
        // do something when clicked
          break;
        }  
    }
    //close navigation drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And add `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to your `Activity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

Remember to initialize and set the listener in `onCreate()`:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```